# How to have multiple models added in Razor page of Blazor app?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a Razor page in my Blazor app. As per my knowledge we can have only one model added to Razor page Editform.
My i have attributes distributed in two -three models. How can I link to all the attributes? Any example or any link I can refer to? Thanks in advance.

Razor page code snippet & `@?` I am not sure which model to use:

```
<div class="card-body">
            <EditForm Model="@?" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <hr />
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label>Role</label><br />
                        <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="Trade.Role" class="form-control">
                            @foreach (var option in rdOptions)
                                {
                                <InputRadio Value="option" /> @option
                                <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
                                }
                        </InputRadioGroup>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Trade.Role)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label>Company Name</label>
                        <InputSelect id="txtCompanyName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@TradePartner.CompanyName">
                            <option selected value="-1">-Select-</option>
                            <option value="CompanyName1">CompanyName1</option>
                            <option value="CompanyName2">CompanyName2</option>
                        </InputSelect>
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => TradePartner.CompanyName)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label>Contact Details of your Trading partner</label>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <InputText @bind-Value="Trade.PartnerName" class="form-control" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Trade.PartnerName)" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <InputText @bind-Value="TradePartner.Email" class="form-control" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => TradePartner.Email)" />
                    </div>
                </div>
 </EditForm>
        </div>
```

.cs code, there are two models Trade & TradePartner:

```
 public partial class CreateTrade
    {

        public Models.Trade Trade { get; set; }
        public Models.TradePartner TradePartner { get; set; }
        List<string> rdOptions = new List<string> { "Seller", "Buyer" };
       
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            Trade = new Models.Trade();
TradePartner = new Models.TradePartner();
        }
       
        protected async void HandleValidSubmit()
        {
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/Trade/", Trade);
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It seems to me that if you are operating on 2 different models, you should make 2 different sub-components.  That feels cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a class encapsulating both models, like:

```
public class TradeViewModel
{
    public Models.Trade Trade { get; set; }
    public Models.TradePartner TradePartner { get; set; }

    public TradeViewModel()
    {
        Trade = new();
        TradePartner = new();
    }
}
```

And use this new model in your EditForm.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried somethin like that. 
If I use TradeDto in ediform @model=TradeDto. How to use this for each field in razor page? It has to be @bind-value= TradeDto.role?

Comment: I had done above comment way but it was not recognising the attributes in child models.

Comment: If you have initialized TradeDto model name as TradeDto, then - TradeDto.Trade.Role

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: Good solution but this is not a DTO - it is a ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class TradeViewModel.cs (ViewModel) and put in it all objects you need in your razor page.
Then you just include @Model TradeViewModel.cs

```cs
class TradeViewModel
{
     public TradePartner TradePartner;
     public Trade Trade;
}
```

in your page file (.cshtml)

```
@model=TradeViewModel
```

Comment: All the models are created as per DB. You mean create Parent model and add required objects? Any snippet you can show? I have a doubt on this

Comment: Currently you are using two models (TradePartner, Trade). You can put these two in TradeViewModel.cs as shwon
`public class TradeViewModel
{
    public TradePartner TradePartner;
    public Trade Trade;
}
`

Then in your razor page on top of your file you can include 
`@model=TradeViewModel.cs`

Comment: Ok I think this matches the one Meer has answered.

Comment: Yes, seems about the same, try that

Comment: Hi, did you say creating a parent model itself. and include Trade & TradePartnerDet as child model in it?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you create a PageModel that holds all the models as properties that you want to pass to the Razor page.

This is similar to a viewmodel in mvc where you select what properties from multiple models you want to pass to the page/view.

Here is a good resource to get going:
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/pagemodel

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I am not sure how page model is going to me help me in this situation .

Comment: PageModel is a Razor Pages concept - it is a ViewModel and Controller in one. You don't want the controller part in Blazor.